# Can select * vs select columns needed give different results?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using a query which gives the sum of max sales of apple products and Samsung products.

I have used union to display both like this

```
Select max(amount) from abc 
Where product = 'apple'
Union 
Select max(amount) from abc 
Where product = 'samsung'
```

I am getting different values when I use `select *` all columns in abc vs `select columns` needed.

Can there be a case in union where the values of `select *` and the selecting columns needed vary?

Comment: This is a little confusing. I think providing the table schema will make it a little more clear. Or at least a complete example - include the columns you have specified plus one or two other columns.

Comment: Is `samsungamount` even a real column?

Comment: Please provide some sample data, expected results and actual results.

Comment: "I am using a query which gives the sum of max sales of apple products and Samsung products."  Perhaps you are using such a query, but that is not the query in your question, which is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that conditional aggregation may be what you are after here:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN product = 'apple'   THEN amount END) AS max_apple_amount,
    MAX(CASE WHEN product = 'samsung' THEN amount END) AS max_samsung_amount
FROM abc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there might be differences. And that's because the `UNION` is performing `DISTINCT`, meaning if you have selected rows with the same values in each column, only one of them will be returned.

Lately, if you perform some aggregation like `SUM` or `COUNT` you will have different results. For example:

```
DECLARE @DataSource01 TABLE
(
    [ColA] INT
   ,[ColB] INT 
   ,[ColC] INT
);

DECLARE @DataSource02 TABLE
(
    [ColA] INT
   ,[ColB] INT 
   ,[ColC] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource01 ([colA], [ColB], [ColC])
VALUES (1, 1, 1)
      ,(1, 1, 2)
      ,(1, 2, 3);


INSERT INTO @DataSource02 ([colA], [ColB], [ColC])
VALUES (1, 1, 4)
      ,(1, 1, 5)
      ,(1, 2, 6);

SELECT *
FROM @DataSource01
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM @DataSource02;

SELECT [colA], [ColB]
FROM @DataSource01
UNION 
SELECT [colA], [ColB]
FROM @DataSource02;
```

[image]

In your case, it will be better to use:

```
SELECT MAX(IIF(product = 'apple', amount, NULL)
      ,MAX(IIF(product = 'samsung', amount, NULL)
FROM abc;
```

Comment: @user13786138 `UNION ALL` will not remove duplicates.

Comment: So will that ignore the change in values when I use select * vs select columns needed?

Comment: @user13786138 You can test it. Without your actual data is hard to tell what will be result.

Answer (score 0):

Prob is not with the query but with the interpretation.

Since you are using max(amount) and only 2 products (apple and samsung) it will give you either two records, and 1 record of both the max(amount) is same. As you are using Union and it discard duplicates.

More if you want the same query without union use below

```
Select cola, colb, colc, max(amount) from abc where product in ('apple','samsung') group by cola, colb, colc;
```

please note cola, colb , colc are name of columns in your table.

Similarly if you want union wise same result, use the columns and group by and then see the results.

Let me know if you understand it and need any help with the actual query.

Answer (score 0):

You have to group by columns when selecting columns with Max(amount).
The query is :

```
select col1,col2...,Max(amount) from abc where product in ('apple','samsung') group by col1,col2...
```

If you want all detail of Max amount row and count by product.I will suggest you this query:

```
select * from (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY amount DESC) AS rn FROM abc) tmp where product in ('apple','samsung') and rn=1
```